# What does "jmp *" mean in 6502 assembly?

Tags: assembly, 6502, atari-800

Right now I am learning 6502 assembly. Currently I am using the MADS assembler to program for the Atari 800. This program is just a small tutorial program that came with the assembler zip file I downloaded. The only piece of this program I did't understand is the `jmp *` operation, what does the '*' mean? Full program:

```
sm_ptr  = $58
ch  = $2f4  
chr = $2400 
rom_chr = $e000 
org $2000
.proc main  
mva #>chr ch    
ldx #0      
copy_loop
mva rom_chr,x chr,x
mva rom_chr+$100,x chr+$100,x
mva rom_chr+$200,x chr+$200,x
mva rom_chr+$300,x chr+$300,x
inx
bne copy_loop
ldx #0      
space_loop
mva charset.space,x chr,x
inx
cpx #8
bne space_loop 
ldy #0       
loop    
tya
sta (sm_ptr),y
iny
bne loop
jmp *
.local charset
space   
.byte %01000100 
.byte %00101000
.byte %01111100
.byte %01010100
.byte %11111110
.byte %10101010
.byte %10111010
.byte %00000000
.endl
.endp   
run main
```

Comment: What is `mva`? Is it a macro or does the Atari 800 have a non standard 6502?

Comment: It’s a macro predefined in MADS.

Comment: `MVA` is a move macro to transfer a byte using A as buffer. `MVA adr1,adr2` gets resolved as `LDA adr1` followed by `STA adr2`.

Comment: '*' means the current assembly address, so this just means jump back to the same instruction.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[MADS](http://mads.atari8.info/) uses `*` in three ways (See [MADS "Manual"](http://mads.atari8.info/mads_eng.html#kom))

- Using the current assembly address for calculation of an address, i.e. the one the actual statement is assembled to.
- Multiplying in expressions.
- Mark the beginning of a comment (until line end)

In above listing it will be interpreted as the address the `JMP` instruction is assembled to, so  it will form an [infinite loop](https://www.wired.com/story/apple-infinite-loop-oral-history/), effectively halting the machine until Reset.

Comment: a.k.a [HCF - Halt and Catch Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire)

Comment: Until an interrupt is received, isn't it? AFAICT a standard 6502 doesn't have a power-saving wait state and therefore isn't likely to "catch fire" with this kind of loop anyway (WDC 65C02 has WAI)

Comment: @Random832 Well, yes and no. Interrupts are served, but when finished control isretruned to this loop - unless the interrupt never returns (usual definition for Reset) or manipulates the return address.

Comment: @Random832 The Catch Fire part isn't really meant to be taken literally most of the time.

Answer (score 14):

I suspect the `*` means the current instruction/location, as it does in some other assemblers, like PDP-8.  Often it would be used in an expression like `*-label` in the data section to get something's size, or `*+3` perhaps, in code.

If that's the case for 6502 assembly, then `jmp *` means branch to self, or, infinite loop, which would be a form of halting the program.

This makes some sense as it comes at the end of main, which presumably has nothing to return to for a bare metal program.

Some assemblers (e.g. masm, Microsoft's x86 assembler) use $ for the same meaning.

Comment: It could, it doesn't seem to effect the main program. I'll test that hypothesis right now.

Comment: Thanks, it is correct that it is an infinite loop that just loops back the the same line.

Comment: FYI, assemblers that don't use `*` to mean the current location typically use `.`. The latter worked its way into other applications, e.g. editors like `ed` use it to mean the current line, and in Emacs many commands and function names use the word `point` to refer to the current buffer position.